# Jasmine: check if a variable is an empty function

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

In my controller I've a statement assigning an empty function in a variable based on a condition.

```
var vm = this;
vm.emptyFunction = angular.isFunction(callback) ? callback : function() {};
```

How can I test that this `vm.emptyFunction` is actually an empty function?

Things which didn't work:

```
expect(vm.emptyFunction).toEqual({});
expect(vm.emptyFunction()).toEqual({});
expect(vm.emptyFunction).toEqual(() => {}); //using typescript
```

Thing which work is:

```
expect(vm.emptyFunction).toEqual(jasmine.any(Function));
```

But this will get valid for any function definition.

Comment: Why would you want to test for this case? Can `emptyFunction` be defined from outside and if it's an empty function this would be an error? Is the function empty by default and should be assigned with a proper function so that you want to test for the uninitialized attribute of your module under test?

Comment: here `callback` is injected in the controller. I need to test if I pass an undefined `callback`, then `vm.emptyFunction` is an empty function instead of the `callback`.

Comment: Then testing for type `function` in the former case and testing whether or not the callback was called should be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is to use the same reference to the same empty function.

```
var emptyFunction = function {};
```

and then use

```
vm.emptyFunction = angular.isFunction(callback) ? callback : emptyFunction;
```

Then test

```
expect(vm.emptyFunction).toEqual(emptyFunction);
```

Comment: In that case, I've to pass the reference of `emptyFunction` from outside. Here `callback` is injected in the controller. I need to check if I pass `callback` as undefined, then `vm.emptyFunction` should be an empty function instead of the `callback`.